# Trying to send messages between Docker containers using rabbitmq

Tags: java, docker, rabbitmq

I'm currently experimenting with Docker and rabbitmq using the Java client, and I'm trying to figure out how to send a simple message i.e. "Hello world" between one container holding the Send class, to a second container running the rabbitmq server, and then to a third container holding the Receive class. Can anyone help with trying to set this up or if this isn't actually possible?
So far what I've done is on the send and receive containers I'm running Ubuntu with Java installed and with the java client in the memory, and I have these both linked through the link command to the server container. On trying to run either class I get a number of "unable to connect" errors, and don't know how to solve it. If anyone could help that would be great. Thanks!

*Edit

I'm trying to run just the simple send and receive classes from the rabbitmq tutorial. For the send container the Dockerfile I'm using is

```
FROM ubuntu
RUN apt-get update
RUN apt-get install software-properties-common -y
RUN add-apt-repository ppa:webupd8team/java -y
RUN apt-get update
RUN echo debconf shared/accepted-oracle-license-v1-1 select true | debconf-set-selections
RUN apt-get install oracle-java8-installer -y
RUN apt-get install oracle-java8-set-default
ADD Send.class /usr/
ADD rabbitmq-java-client-bin-3.5.3.zip /usr/
```

And similar for the Receive container. 
I'm starting the rabbitmq server container with

```
docker run --name server1 rabbitmq:3
```

then starting the send container with

```
docker run -i -t -d -P --name send --link server1 sendtest
```

Inside the send container I unzip the java client, then try to run the send class but get the connection refused error. I know there's something I'm missing, just not sure what it is.
Thanks

Comment: What exactly are you running within the classes? How are you referring to the rabbitMQ-server? If you linked your containers to the server you can then refer to the ip of the server by using the alias you used in the `--link containername:alias`

Comment: Can you show your dockerfiles (or at least parts of them) ? And show which arguments you pass to docker run ?

Comment: Just added more info to the post, thanks

Answer (score 0):

I have gotten this to work quite well using Docker Compose.  If you want to use Docker run it should work too if you specify the ports in the rabbitMQ run. Something like

docker run --expose 5672 -P --name server1 rabbitmq:3